# Conditionals or marker count on Google Maps for expression engine

Tags: ee2, google-maps-for-ee, google-maps, objective-html

I've got a channel in EE with a 'Google Maps for EE' fieldtype and what I'm trying to achieve is to not display the map in the template if the content editor has not added a marker to the map.

Is there a conditional or marker count available that could be used in the templates?

Running EE2.73 and Google Maps for EE 3.3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this variable:

https://www.objectivehtml.com/google-maps/fieldtype#total_markers

Regard's.

Comment: Using total_markers was the solution but was throwing a php error. Developer fixed since.